# Authentication issue with mongo in node-red

Tags: node-red

I am trying to use a mongo connection in node-red to store records from a financial datastream captured using websockets.

The mongo database does not have a user or password defined (internal use only) and I can connect without issue from the command line, view, create, update and delete documents with no issues.

However when I try to define the mongo conenection in node-red it fails.

Here are the log messages:

```html
12 Jan 21:55:13 - [info] 

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

12 Jan 21:55:13 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5
12 Jan 21:55:13 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.11.1
12 Jan 21:55:13 - [info] Darwin 16.7.0 x64 LE
12 Jan 21:55:14 - [info] Loading palette nodes
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/xxx/.node-red/settings.js
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] User directory : /Users/xxx/.node-red
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] Flows file     : /Users/xxx/.node-red/flows_yyy.lan.json
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] Starting flows
MongoNode {
  id: '3fd17db4.76dcc2',
  type: 'mongodb',
  z: '',
  _closeCallbacks: [],
  wires: [],
  _wireCount: 0,
  send: [Function],
  credentials: {},
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '27017',
  db: 'cryptoboard',
  name: '' }





 { id: '3fd17db4.76dcc2',
  type: 'mongodb',
  z: '',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '27017',
  db: 'cryptoboard',
  name: '',
  _users: [ 'c956716f.01d8f' ] }
mongodb://undefined:undefined@localhost:27017/cryptoboard
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [info] Started flows
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [error] [mongodb out:c956716f.01d8f] MongoError: Authentication failed.
12 Jan 21:55:15 - [warn] [websocket-client:719daa1a.430f64] ws:undefined : Error: not opened
```

Here is the flow:

[image]
Here is the mongo configuration:

[image]

Any thoughts?

I was considering adding a user and password but I don't want to do that yet; it should work if there is no user or password required?

Comment: What version of the mongodb node are you using. The latest code on github should not show this behaviour.

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
I am running Mongo on a mac. Does this make any difference?

Comment: I didn't ask what version of mongo, I asked what version of the Mongo node-red node do you have installed.

Comment: My apologies - Node-RED version: v0.17.5
Does the version of node matter? If it does it is v6.11.1

Comment: Again not what I asked for, Not what version of Node-RED or NodeJS, I asked for the version of the node-red-node-mongodb you have installed.

Comment: Hello; node-red-mongodb version is 0.0.18. I'll see if there is a more recent one available.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that's the problem. You are using `node-red-mongodb` when you probably should be using `node-red-node-mongodb` (note the extra `-node` in the name).

`node-red-mongodb` looks to be a very old fork of the "official" `node-red-node-mongodb` node shipped by the Node-RED team and is missing a bunch of fixes.

You need to uninstall `node-red-mongodb` and install `node-red-node-mongodb` at version 0.0.13 (which is the latest) and this will fix your problem.